# Why do NetworkX's approximations for vertex cover not include self-loop nodes?

Tags: python, networkx

The definition of vertex cover according to [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/approximation/vertex_cover.html):

> A vertex cover is a subset of nodes such that each edge in the graph is incident to at least one node in the subset.

I tried the following code. However, the returned vertex cover set lacks the self-connected nodes. Why is that?

```
import networkx
from networkx.algorithms.approximation import vertex_cover, min_weighted_dominating_set
import numpy as np

r=np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(1,5), p=[0.6, 0.4])
a=r.T*r
np.fill_diagonal(a, 1)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=100)

G = networkx.from_numpy_array(a)
networkx.draw(G,pos=networkx.random_layout(G),font_size=8, with_labels=True)
plt.show()

print(vertex_cover.min_weighted_vertex_cover(G))
```

will output:

```
{0}
```

[image]

As one can see from the [link](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/approximation/vertex_cover.html) to NetworkX's source code:

```
    for u, v in G.edges():
        min_cost = min(cost[u], cost[v])
        cost[u] -= min_cost
        cost[v] -= min_cost
    return {u for u, c in cost.items() if c == 0}
```

Because for a self-looped edges `u==v`, we will get `cost[u]!=0` for which the the condition `c==0` in `u for u, c in cost.items() if c == 0` does not apply.

Comment: Likely whoever wrote the algorithm was assuming a simple graph.  You might raise this here: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues.  (aside, could you update the link to the networkx documentation to a page with the definition you've given?)

Comment: @Joel thanks. https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/5103

Comment: A fix was merged to newtorkx 2.7. https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/5104